# Colocar valor em tudo que está null no mysql

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho o seguinte problema,criei uma tabela no mysql adicionei todos os registros e após isso criei uma chave estrangeira nela, nesta tabela contém informações de apenas uma "coisa",entretanto futuramente terá de mais coisas.
Queria saber se existe uma query que substitui tudo que está Null por outro valor,não adianta eu mudar no default pois futuramente este valor terá que mudar

Comment: `update tabelea set campo = 'outro valor' where campo is null`. Não?

Comment: '-'   oh god........

Comment: @Rafael, fui eu que dei o -1 e explico desde já porque: Não apresenta esforço de pesquisa. Se tiveres alguma coisa a argumentar, ficas a vontade

Comment: Aqui não é o lugar e nem a hora. No entanto, ajudem mais. Não joguem somente -1. E se está tão certo disso, por que retirou?

Answer (score 5):

Pelo que eu entendi você tinha algo assim:

```
TabelaX
|--------------------|
| ColA | ColB | ColC |
|------|------|------|
| 1    | 'ab' |  3   |
| 2    | 'ac' |  3   |
| 3    | 'ad' |  5   |
|--------------------|
```

Você criou uma nova coluna e os valores já existentes estão com `NULL`;

```
TabelaX
|---------------------------|
| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
|------|------|------|------|
| 1    | 'ab' |  3   | null |
| 2    | 'ac' |  3   | null |
| 3    | 'ad' |  5   | null |
|---------------------------|
```

Você quer alterar para um valor específico, bastaria usar:

```
UPDATE TabelaX SET ColD = 1;
```

Caso não consiga, pode ser que o servidor do banco está com o modo de atualização seguro habilitado (ou seja, necessita de uma clausula `where` para o `update` funcionar), você poderia usar `1=1` que sempre será verdadeiro e irá atualizar todos os registros.

```
UPDATE TabelaX SET ColD = 1 WHERE 1=1;
```

Resultado:

```
TabelaX
|---------------------------|
| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
|------|------|------|------|
| 1    | 'ab' |  3   |  1   |
| 2    | 'ac' |  3   |  1   |
| 3    | 'ad' |  5   |  1   |
|---------------------------|
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo amigo, eu tinha tentado assim mas estava com o modo de atualização seguro,a segunda forma funcionou.Obg

Answer (score 3):

O comando para atualizar registros é `UPDATE`, que tem a seguinte sintaxe:

```
UPDATE nome_tabela
SET CAMPO = "novo_valor"
WHERE campo is null
```

Faça isto quando precisar atualizar os campos que estiverem null, que é o seu caso.